# Problemas con el e.target

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo una función que calcula el precio de una reserva de habitación según el tipo de hab, y la cantidad de días. El problema es que utilizo event.target; y el programa me dice que no reconoce el evento.. paso código para ver si alguien puede auxiliarme

````
    ```let myForm = document.getElementById('form');
       myForm.addEventListener("submit", filterRooms);```

        ```function filterRooms(e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          if (myForm.adultos.value < 2 && myForm.ninios.value == 0 )  {
          let room = rooms.filter(habitacion => habitacion.capacity < 3);
          console.log(room);
          howManyDays(checkIn, checkOut);
 
        filtered.innerHTML = ` <div class= "row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <h3 class="h3 text-center">Suite 1</h3>
                                <div class="images">
                                    <img src="${room[0].img1}">
                                    <img src="${room[0].img2}">
                                </div>
                                <span class="price">$${room[0].price} por noche</span>
                                
                               
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class= "row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <h3 class="h3 text-center">Suite 2</h3>
                                <div class="images">
                                    <img src="${room[0].img3}">
                                    <img src="${room[0].img4}">
                                </div>
                                <span class="price">$${room[0].price} por noche</span>
                                <div class="buttons">
                                <button id= "${room[0].id}" class="reserve">Reservar ahora 
     </button> ```
````

Ese es el fragmento de código en el cual creo dinámicamente a partir de un array un div con un botón con clase "reserve" al cual quiero agragarle el addEventListener... paso a continuación la parte que no me estaría funcionando..

````
    ``` function howManyDays(date1, date2) {
        let totalMs = Math.abs(date2.valueAsDate - date1.valueAsDate);
        days = totalMs = Math.round(totalMs/msPerDay);
        console.log(days)

     } ```

     ``` const totalPrice = e => {
        if (e.target.classList.contains("reserve")) {
        const findRoom = rooms.find(room => room.id == e.target.id);
        console.log(findRoom);
        price = findRoom.price * days;
        console.log(price);
        }
    } ```
````

El error me sale en la función totalPrice.. si alguien pudiera ayudarme estaría muy agradecido ya que hace días le doy vueltas a esto..

Comment: Si puedes 1. Edita un poco mejor el codigo que no se lee muy bien
2. Veo que tienes un </a> que no parece estar bien dentro de el <button>
3. Agrega la parte del codigo donde agregas el eventListener es impotante saber como lo estas haciendo

Comment: @JuanSolano No sé como editar el código para que lo veas mejor (no tengo que aclarar que recién empiezo con esto)..  Listo el error de la etiqueta <a> ya la quité y el evento lo tengo así:                                                                         
let myForm = document.getElementById('form');
myForm.addEventListener("submit", filterRooms);    En el primer mensaje también lo arregle para que se vea mejor

Comment: exactamente cual es el error, podrias compartirlo? nos ayudaria mas a entender mas el error

Comment: functions.js:139 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target')
    at totalPrice (functions.js:139:11)
    at HTMLElement.showMessage (functions.js:149:5)

Comment: la linea 149 llama a la función totalPrice

Comment: y la 139 está el e.target... dentro de la función totalPrice

Comment: ¿Y como llamas a totalPrice?  No veo la linea que lo invoca, ni creo que esa sintaxis sea correcta, ni comprendo porque usas una [funcion flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) con las limitaciones que tiene

Comment: Son como 160 líneas de código,  no mostré la parte en que la llamo xq no me pareció relevante ya que el error que me muestra por consola es el que describí arriba con la palabra target.. usé la función flecha xq lo vi en un ejemplo en el curso que estoy haciendo..de todas maneras tmbn probé con una función común y no anduvo tampoco

Comment: Pues con una funcion comun a mi si me va, al menos me entra dentro del if, pero claro, luego peta porque me falta mucho codigo por resolver... miralo aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/6rsLm1qx/

Comment: Okey en cuanto tenga mi ordenador a mano lo pruebo.. gracias